# how to adjust the parameters of backgroundSubtractorMOG

Tags: python, opencv, background-subtraction

So I know there are a few parameters that I can set and I am not really sure about the **nmixtures, backgroundRatio and noseSigma**

```
Python: cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG([history[, nmixtures[, backgroundRatio[, noiseSigma]]]]) → retval
Parameters: 
history – Length of the history.
nmixtures – Number of Gaussian mixtures.
backgroundRatio – Background ratio.
noiseSigma – Noise strength (standard deviation of the brightness or each color channel). 0 means some automatic value.
```

I looked to find a good explanation on how to properly adjust these parameters but I didn't find anything. Can someone suggest a proper way to adjust these based on data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think anyone could tell you which parameter is what if you don't know the details of the algorithm that you are using.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808831/parameter-of-backgroundsubtractormog2/22891194#22891194) answer, which is given to the exact same question.